# map function in reactjs looping twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am using two **functional components** named **Bord** and **Square** where the Bord component have a **multidimensional array** called **boxes** which have two value's on the first level, which means the length of the box is 2 with index 0 and 1,

```
    [
            [
                [1,2,3,4],
                [5,6,7,8]
            ],
            [
                [9,10,11,12],
                [13,14,15,16]
            ]
    ]
```

I am looping through the boxes array and passing the child array in Square component  and before that, I am logging the array with its index number I have shared the code as well as the screenshot of the console in the browser you can see that the log has been entered twice in the console I would like to understand that how it can be possible?

**Bord.js**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import  Square from "./Square";

function Bord(){
var [boxes,setBox]=useState(
    [
        [
            [1,2,3,4],
            [5,6,7,8]
        ],
        [
            [9,10,11,12],
            [13,14,15,16]
        ]
    ]
);

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("length of the box",boxes.length);
},[boxes]);
    return(
        <div>
            {
            boxes.map((subArray,index)=>{
                    console.log(subArray,index);
                    return <Square key={index} values={subArray} />;
            })
            }      
        </div>
    );
}

export default Bord;
```

**Square.js**

```
import React from 'react';


function Square(props) {

    return (
        <div style={{ marginLeft: "50%" }}>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {props.values.map((val, index) => { return <td key={index}>{val}</td> })}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Square;
```

[image: console Image]

Comment: I might be easier to create a a function that uses a nested loop to return the html than in the component return. That way you can use other for loops etc

Comment: I have tested your code here -> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-fjkzq?file=/src/index.tsx and the behavior you described is not reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

this is most probably because of [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) , try removing `<React.StrictMode>` from `index.js`, but it's often helpful during development

Answer (score 0):

is due to the useEffect() Hook, it renders every time the state changes, I would not worry about it logging twice the state wont be affected.

You could have other logic inside the useEffect hook to terminate if a condition is truthy but it will still be triggered is the state changes.

Answer (score 0):

this is happens due to the nature of the useEffect hook it's designed to be called each time the component re rendered /updated

Answer (score -1):

You can easily fix this problem by using a useState([])

something like this :

```
const [stories,setStories] =useState([])
```